# Get the sum of specific value of object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
 $scope.showReport = function(datas){
    data.post('dailyReservationReport',{date:$scope.date}).then(function (response){
        $scope.reports = response.data;
        console.log($scope.reports);

        var sum =0;
        for(var index in $scope.reports){
            if($scope.reports[index].departuredate == "2015-03-11"){
              sum += $scope.reports[index].departuredate;
            }
        }
        console.log(sum);

    })
};
```

The problem I was have is I want to get the sum of data with departure date which is equal to `2015-03-11`. I have 2 data so the sum should output 2.

But this is the results in my console.log:

```
02015-03-112015-03-11
```

What I did wrong? Please help

Comment: you are adding date here not data. try something like this: `sum += $scope.reports[index].data` or whatever key it has instead of `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the line in your question::  **"I have 2 data so the sum should output 2"**., i think you just need to increment `sum`, as:

```
var sum =0;
for(var index in $scope.reports){
    if($scope.reports[index].departuredate == "2015-03-11"){
        sum++;
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use `parseInt()` because our value stored in `var` data type it will be in string format, if we are doing addition for this then it will return Concatenation of string , So we have to use `parseInt()`.

```
var sum =0;
    for(var index in $scope.reports){
        if($scope.reports[index].departuredate == "2015-03-11"){
          sum = parseInt(sum)+parseInt($scope.reports[index].departuredate); -->changed this line
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also count items with a certain departure date using a filter:

`$filter('filter')($scope.reports, { 'departuredate': '2015-03-11' }).length`